# Resolving type="binary" within RTF fields

Tags: content-delivery

We're using this tbb http://sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/process-download-links.aspx - from the sdl tridion world website.

This updates mm item links in the output to append the attribute tridion:type="Binary" (on the "tridion:href" links only)

When we publish our content, the link isn't getting resolved (normal component links are working)...

My question is - does this mean we must resolve these link CD side?  or does the OOTB cd linking take care of it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few possible things to check...

1. I guess that your `Output` contains something like:
   `<a href="" tridion:href="@@Component.ID@@" tridion:type="binary">link</a>`
2. The OOTB CD Linking should take care of it.  Are you getting the correct tag on the webserver?
   e.g. In ASP.NET
   `<tridion:BinaryLink runat="server" BinaryURI="tcm:55-12345" VariantID="" Anchor="" LinkText="My link" TextOnFail="true"/>`
3. Have you confirmed that the Multimedia Components are definitely being added in to the package and that the `Publish Binaries In Package` TBB (or similar) is part of the Default Finish Actions?
4. Are the file extensions of the items that you are trying to publish in the TBB's Parameters in the CT (e.g. doc,docx,zip,etc.)?
5. Is the multimedia item definitely being published on to the site (or database) correctly?